# Make MessageBodyWriter to not consume Resource classes and returning sub Resource class in resource one

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I wanna create rest api. I don't wanna repeat myself in each resource class with absolute path, so I was thinking to make it hierarchical.
so instead of something like:

```
@Path("/")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class UsersResource extends Application {

    @GET @Path("users/{id}/roles") 
    public Role usersResource(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    }
}
```

I wanna return dependant resource like follow:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class UsersResource {
    @Inject private UserRolesResource userRolesResource;

    @GET @Path("{id}/roles") public UserRolesResource getRolesResource(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return userRolesResource.withUserId(id);
    }
}


@Component
@Scope("request")
public class UserRolesResource {
    private Long userId;

    @GET public String getAll() {
        return userId + "=r1, r2, r3";
    }

    @GET @Path("{id}") public String getById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return "userId " + userId + "roleId=" + id;
    }

    public UserRolesResource withUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        return this;
    }
}
```

As You can see I am trying to return `UserRolesResource` class, instead of data. I would like to jersey/jaxrs now that to not serialize Resource classes, instead it should move control to returned resources and there allow to handle and serialize correctly.

I use spring boot with jaxrs and jersey.

I not it is possible as I saw running solution, I am just missing some body writer configuration probably.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oh in place where I was returning sub resource I had `@GET` annotation with is illegal on sub resource entry: `@GET @Path("{id}/roles") public UserRolesResource getRolesResource(@PathParam("id") Long id) {`

After removing `@GET` it worked.